# jquery added html code not worked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I started new project and I use jquery to add content to article

when I create a slider with this code:

```
$(".inserttabtext1").click(function () {
    var count = parseInt($(".firsttabtextcount").attr("name"), 10);
    var name = parseInt($(this).attr("name"));
    var id = "#" + name;
    var idi,idt,content,idic,idtc;
    content = "<div class='short-tabs'><ul>";
    for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        idi = "#ftti" + i;
        idic = $(idi).val();
        if (i == 1) 
        {
            content += "<li class='active'><a href='#'> " + i + idic + "</a></li>";
        }
        else
        {
            content += "<li><a href='#'> "+ i + idic +"</a></li>";
        }
    }
    content += "</ul>";
    for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) 
    {
        if (i==1) 
        {
            content += "<div class='active'>";
        }
        else
        {
            content += "<div>";
        }
        idt = "#fttt" +i;
        idtc = $(idt).val();
        content += "<p class='text-go-center'>"+idtc+"</p></div>";
    }
    content += "</div>";
    $(id).html(content);
});
```

and put them into html code my text slider not worked

but when I put manual html code in my page it work

I use these code for copy my html code

```
$(id).html(content);
$(id).append(content);
```

where is my wrong?

Comment: The slider is obviously being initiated in your JS somewhere, on page load.  Since youre dynamically adding elements, it wont work, unless you re-initialize it.  Find where and how the sliders are initiated, and just add that in your function at the end, so the elements get initiailized with a slider

Comment: Please include the javascript and HTML that starts your page on document Load. Also, please include some sample data that you use to generate the slider.

Comment: Aaron when I Added my html code manually to my project My code work
but when I Added it with jquery it not work
I use this code for adding my code to html
$("body").html(content); and $("body").append(content);

Comment: When you say it did not work, what did not work. These elements were not rendered or events associated to then were not working. Also please share your markup.

Answer (score 0):

create a function and put your slider codes inside it, then call it in $(document).ready, and call it again after adding html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Init();
});

function Init(){
    //Call your slide function here
}
```

call Init after Adding Html

```
$(id).html(content);
$(id).append(content);
Init();
```

Comment: I cant do it because I don't know this page has slider or not
user decide that want to slider or not

Comment: how do you initialize your slider? however you need to initialize it again after adding HTML, maybe i could help you if i see whole js code